# Angular RxJs get only count of values then emit

Tags: angular, rxjs

What I have :
Service, in service subject and observable created from that subject.
I'm emitting e.g 3 times using 'subject.next' from 3 separate components, and subscribing in another component.

What I want to achieve ?
In my subscription filter by property, get only two first emitted values, get value with max value in property, automatically unsubscribe.

What I've tried:

```
const validValues = ['a','b']

this.myService.pipe(
   filter(x => validValues.some(y => y === x.name)),
   max((a,b) => a.value - b.value),
   take(2)
)
```

Take(2) is not working, still getting 3 values.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: The order of the operator matters. Try moving the `take(2)` before the `max()` operator.

Answer (score 0):

max operator works when the source observable completes. And since the observable encapsulated by subject won't complete by default, the snippet you mentioned will never emit, unless you invoke subject.complete(). I am assuming this.myService is the subject.

```
this.myService.pipe(
   filter(x => validValues.some(y => y === x.name)),
   max((a,b) => a.value - b.value),
   take(2)
).subscribe(console.log)
this.myService.complete()
```

Having said that, what you want to achieve can be done by placing the take operator atleast before max operator. Take will unsubscribe after 2 emissions completing the source observable for max operator.
Now, based on if you want to take 2 emissions after/before filtering you can place take() after/before filter().